# Alternative to AdSense

Tags: advertising, recommendations

What are some alternatives to using Google AdSense for generating advertising revenue?

Google requires that the website has a high enough traffic volume to make it worth while to them. My website is for different seasonal volunteer groups so the traffic is rather low. We still want advertising but we want it focused on things that users are interested in.

An example of this is National Ski Patrol, it's volunteer, but we buy a lot of ski/snow related equipment, so we want to see advertisements from places to purchase ski patrol related equipment such as ski gloves.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want an alternative? Is it about the type of ads displayed, the type of site you want to host the ads on, or something else? This will help people to suggest the best alternatives.

Comment: I run a volunteer ski patrol website.   The traffic is not high, but with 150+ members many of them actually want to see ski equipment related adverts.  We're all equipment whores (boots, skis, avie shovels, etc)

Answer (score 5):

The following services are alternatives to Google's AdSense:

- [Bidvertiser](http://www.bidvertiser.com/)
- [Chitika](http://chitika.com/)
- [Infolinks](http://www.infolinks.com/)
- [Clicksor](http://www.clicksor.com/)

Comment: This is just a long list of undetailed ad networks. How about breaking this up into one answer per network so everyone can vote on their favourite and say why it's good?

Comment: Adbrite has closed up shop.

Answer (score 1):

Also you should check amazon affiliate program, you get a small percentage of every item bought through your banner/link/gadget.

Answer (score 1):

@BozoJoe Google AdSense will have the most relevant ads, your next best option is to signup for affiliate account on sites such as liftopia.com and display their affiliate ads, then rotate them which would all be Ski related.

Answer (score -2):

MGID also one of the good option

```
http://www.mgid.com/
```